# Change image outside collectionView when scrolling the collectionView cells

Tags: ios, swift

I’m searching for a way where you can change an image in a imageView when you scroll to another cell in a collectionView.

[image: myimage]

So when scrolling the cell’s (1) I want to change the image (2).

What is the best way to create this?

I already did a lot of research but never found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UICollectionView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` so,

1. Firstly set delegate of **collectionView** to your **ViewController** 
   :`collectionView.delegate = self`
2. Now set your **ViewController** to conform to `UIScrollViewDelegate`
3. Now implement `scrollViewDidScroll` like :

   ```
   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
       let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: collectionView.contentOffset, size: collectionView.bounds.size)
       let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)
       let visibleIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint)
   }
   ```
4. In the above piece of code we'll get the visible item for your `collectionView`.
5. Now you can use this `visibleIndexPath` to update your outer image.

   ```
   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
       let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: collectionView.contentOffset, size: collectionView.bounds.size)
       let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)
       let visibleIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint)
       outerImageView.image = UIImage(named: outerImageNames[visibleIndexPath.row])
   }
   ```

Here `outerImageView` refers to your outer image and `outerImageNames` is an **array of strings of your image names**.

I have assumed images for outer `UIImageView` to be present in your bundle. But if the images are coming from some other source, then the image setting logic can be tweaked. In case of images coming from an async API (FileSystem or Network call), I would strongly suggest to make use of heavy caching (If that is the case consider using [KingFisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) or [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)).