# How can I change an ImageView outside of CollectionView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView on top of an imageView and an array of images. I want the image inside the imageView to change based on the cell that's visible on screen, for example if the third cell is on screen I want the image inside my imageView to update to the third image inside my image array.
I try'ed a lot of ways but it didn't work for me, can you help me with an answer? Thanks!

Comment: Provide your code where you tried anything.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this link that's answering my question: [Change image outside collectionView when scrolling the collectionView cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54154782/change-image-outside-collectionview-when-scrolling-the-collectionview-cells)

here is also the code and you can simply include this in your scrollview functions, it will correctly display the cell that's visible

```
let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: collectionView.contentOffset, size: collectionView.bounds.size)
let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)
let visibleIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint)

nearCollectionImage.image = pinImagesDownloaded[visibleIndexPath?.row ?? 0] //this sets my imageView to the right image inside my array
```

let me know if you also have an answer